# calling instance method on model and passing its parameters

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have model.rb

```
class Foo
  def baz(param1, param2, param3, param4)
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```

controller.rb

```
def signup
  param4 = params[:param4] || 'N'
  begin
    @foo.baz(Integer(params[:param1]),
                              params[:param2],
                              params[:param3],
                              param4)
    head :ok
  rescue ArgumentError => e
    render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
  end
end
```

Is this the right way to call instance method on model? also should this `param4 = params[:param4] || 'N'` be done in model?

Answer (score 1):

> Is this the right way to call instance method on model?

Yes, if `@foo` is an instance of `Foo`

> should this param4 = params[:param4] || 'N' be done in model?

You can set the last parameter variable on you model to be option like so

```
class Foo
  def baz(param1, param2, param3, param4 = 'N')
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```

And remove the need to set it within the controller

```
def signup
  @foo.baz(Integer(params[:param1]),
                            params[:param2],
                            params[:param3],
                            params[:param4])
  head :ok
rescue ArgumentError => e
  render_error(:bad_request, e.message)
end
```

Since if `params[:param4]` is `nil` it will be set to `'N'` as specified within the `baz` method on the `Foo` model.

Whether or not if you *should* set `param4` in the model is up to you:

- Yes, if setting the last parameter `param4` to `'N'` should or need to occur outside the controller, or
- No, if setting a default value for `param4` is unique to the `signup` controller action and `param4` should not have default set, since it might be used elsewhere

Answer (score 0):

I think you should handle it in model:

```
class Foo
  def baz(param)
    param1 = Integer(params[:param1])
    param2 = params[:param2]
    param3 = params[:param2]
    param4 =  params[:param4] || 'N'
    puts 'something'
  end
end
```